# Convert directory of epub/pdf (and other text files) to .txt using pandoc

Tags: bash, pandoc

This is how far I've gotten:

```
ls $1 | while read x; do echo "pandoc '$x' -o $x" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | sed 's/$/.txt/' | sed 's/$/ --wrap=preserve/' ; done
```

What this does is it prints out the command that you'd have to run for every file to convert a file to TXT using pandoc.

The problem is if you replace `echo` with `eval` it doesn't work. I hypothesize because you are modifying the command after you run it ... somehow? Yet still it's printing properly?

The result I got when I ran it with `eval` was just it copying EPUB files as opposed to converting them which explains my hypothesis.

So my question is, how can I run every command as it's actually printed like so:

```
pandoc 'Complicity - Iain Banks.epub' -o Complicity - Iain Banks.txt --wrap=preserve
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do that:

```
for f in *; do
  pandoc "$f" -o "${f%.*}.txt" --wrap=preserve
done
```

What do you need `ls`/`eval` for?

Comment: @Hmm Try `for f in *` or clarify your question, I have no idea what you're saying